# Google apps script onEdit() function modifying content in web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that displays its responses in a specific sheet called "Student Info" in a spreadsheet. The data in "Student Info" is displayed on a web app. When new responses come in, I want to display all rows and the new rows on the web app.

I cannot figure out how to use the onEdit(e) function to modify the web app or call a function in the web app.

I could probably figure out a way to regularly check to see if new rows have been added and update the web app, but I would like the changes to be displayed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use onEdit(e) because it only fires for User edits.  Instead use an onFormSubmit Trigger.

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Note that there are two of these triggers one is for the form and one is for the trigger.  I recommend using the one for the spreadsheet.  All of the answers to the question are found in either e.values or e.namedValues